# If else with shortcodes

Tags: shortcode, conditional-content

I only want one of these shortcodes to display if the custom field value is true. I'm not understanding the logic to do this. So basically, if there is a twitch video and a own3d video I only want the top video (twitch) to display. So on and so forth. Is this beyond the if else statement?  I'm adding this code of course to my template.php file.

My second question is would this code be better off using the switch method?

```
<?php
$twitch = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'twitch', $single = true );
$own3d = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'own3d', $single = true );
$livestream = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'livestream', $single = true );
$ustream = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ustream', $single = true );
$justin = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'justin', $single = true );


if ($twitch == '') {
}
else { 
echo do_shortcode('[livestream type="twitch" channel="' . $twitch . '"]');
}

if ($own3d == '') {
}
else { 
echo do_shortcode('[livestream type="own3d" channel="' . $own3d . '"]');
}
if ($livestream == '') {
}
```

else { 
   echo do_shortcode('[livestream type="livestream" channel="' . $livestream . '"]');
  }

```
if ($ustream == '') {
}
else {
echo do_shortcode('[livestream type="ustream" channel="' . $ustream . '"]');
}

if ($justin == '') {
}
else {
echo do_shortcode('[livestream type="justin" channel="' . $justin . '"]');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather a simple PHP question and almost off topic. You can simplify your code drastically:

```
$metas = array ( 'twitch', 'own3d', 'livestream', 'ustream', 'justin' );
foreach ( $metas as $meta )
{
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $meta, TRUE );
    if ( $value )
    {
        echo do_shortcode("[livestream type='$meta' channel='$value']");
        break;
    }
}
```

This will run over the list of possible meta fields and stop if it finds one with content.

I wouldn’t use `do_shortcode()` like this. Use the shortcode handler function instead (the function that is called by this shortcode) to speed the processing up.
Use `do_shortcode()` only if you have content *outside* of the shortcode.

Comment: I'm trying to learn. I apologize if it was off topic. More apologies if I'm to newbie for this website.

Comment: Forgot to thank you! Thank you! I understand the array now. :)